# Angular 2—change component selector

Tags: angular, css-selectors, angular-components

The [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html) say to define a component like this, using a magic string for the selector name:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
   selector: 'card',
   template: `
     <div class="card">{{title}}</card>
   `
})
export class Card {
   title = 'Card Title';
}
```

If I do this, am I stuck with `<card>` as the only way to use this component in the future? Can an app have only one type of component with this selector? For example, is it possible to use a `<card>` from a third-party library, and also use my own `<card>`?

This is trivial in React, because component names are just variables.

```js
import OtherCard from 'card'
const Card = title => <div className="card">{title}</div>
const Composable = title => <OtherCard><Card title={title} /></OtherCard>
```

One of the reasons I ask is so I can know whether to namespace Angular 2 component selectors like in Angular 1 and Objective-C:

`selector: 'initech-card'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should namespace Angular2 component selectors (but not with `ng-` ;-) )

I think you can't import 2 modules that contain elements with the same selector (not tried).

This limits you to **one component** with a specific selector **within one module**.
If you encounter a collision you might be able to split your code in 2 modules where one module imports `<card>` from `ModuleA` and the other module imports `<card>` from `ModuleB`.

I wouldn't expect such collisions to happen a lot.

### EDIT (updating answer from comments)

Components are module-scoped, which gives you the ability to use components with third-party components with the same selector, like in the `Composable` React component in the example in the question.

To use a `<card>` you wrote with a third-party `<card>`, you can wrap the third-party component with another  component that is part of an imported module and then use the wrapper component instead.

**update**

For changing the selector of the root component see also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14750
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7136
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13035

Comment: Variables work well if you define the view in code but that's not the way Angular2 chose.

Comment: I really hope manual namespacing isn't the best-practice solution (after 5 years of AngularJS versions) for a problem that is easily solved in. Backbone, Ember, React, Mithril, Snabbdom, Cycle, Elm, CanJS etc. etc. I'm just sure someone must have thought about this problem and there is  a better solution in Angular 2 that I just can't find.

Comment: It's module scoped and therefore rather unlikely that collisions happen. What I know is planned is to allow to pass. a custom selector for the root component.

Comment: @ Günter Zöchbauer thanks for your answer. Could you tell me how module scoping works? That sounds nice: so 3rd-party components would always be in a different module, and my `<card>` would be usable with any third-party `<card>`, meaning there's no problem? Happy to vote up if you post an answer.

Comment: When you build a module you have to import the modules that contain the components that you want to use. You can't import conflicting modules, but you can have "conflicting" elements in different modules. In your app you can use as many elements with the same selector as you want, but in one module they need to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. The part I don't understand is how to use both `card` components in the same template (like in the `Compositional` React component in my question). Is there a way to do that? Sorry for all the follow-up questions, I'm really new to Angular 2.

Comment: You would need to wrap it with another component that is part of an imported module and then use the wrapper component instead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Is the root component custom selector feature available in Angular 2.x yet? [I posted a question here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791148/angular-2-root-component-dynamic-selector)

Comment: I don't follow the changes as closely anymore because of time constraints. I guess this is still not available though.

Comment: There is a recent pull request https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14750 but not yet merged.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you. I am just coming up to speed in Angular. I assume this would only be available in 4? Or will they introduce new features back into previous versions?

Comment: No, new features won't be added to previous versions. There isn't much difference between Angular2 and Angular4 (in contrary to Angular1.x and Angular2). Angular applies versions according to SemVer which requires the major version to increase for breaking changes.