# Angular 2 Root Component - Dynamic Selector

Tags: angular

The following comment was made on a different [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533051/angular-2-change-component-selector)

> What I know is planned is to allow to pass. a custom selector for the root component.

Is this feature available in Angular 2.x? Unfortunately, **dynamic compnonent selector** brings up a slew of information not related to this specific use case.

I know the following is not possible, but it best illustrates what I want:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: Inject('DynamicSelector')
    ...       
})
export class AppComponent {
    ...
}
```

Anyone know of a clean technique to accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent pull request but it wasn't merged yet

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/14750

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7136
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13035